# lisp code excerpt

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i've been reading some lisp code and came across this section, didn't quite understand what it specifically does, though the whole function is supposed to count how many times the letters from a -z appear in an entered text.

```
(do ((i #.(char-code #\a) (1+ i)))
    ((> i #.(char-code #\z)))
```

can anyone explain step by step what is happening? I know that it's somehow counting the letters but not quite sure how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Lisp code is slightly unusual, since it uses read-time evaluation. `#.expr` means that the expression will be evaluated only once, during read-time.

In this case a clever compiler might have guessed that the character code of a given character is known and could have removed the computation of character codes from the `DO` loop. The author of that code chose to do that by evaluating the expressions before the compiler sees it.

The source looks like this:

```
(do ((i #.(char-code #\a) (1+ i)))
    ((> i #.(char-code #\z)))
  ...)
```

When Lisp reads in the s-expression, we get this new code as the result (assuming a usual encoding of characters):

```
(do ((i 97 (1+ i)))
    ((> i 122))
  ...)
```

So that's a loop which counts the variable `i` up from 97 to 122.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp codes are written as [S-Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). In a typical S-Expression sytax, the first element of any S-expression is treated as operator and the rest as operand. Operands can either be an atom or another S-expression. Please note, an atom is a single data object. Keeping this in mind

[char-code](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_char_c.htm)

```
(char-code #\a) - returns the ascii representation of a character here its 'a'.
```

The do syntax looks similar to the below

```
(do ((var1 init1 step1)
     (var2 init2 step2)
     ...)
    (end-test result)
 statement1
  ...)
```

So in your example

```
(do ((i #.(char-code #\a) (1+ i)))
    ((> i #.(char-code #\z)))
    )
```

The first s-expression operand of do is the loop initialization, the second s-expression operand is the end-test. 
So this means you are simply iterating over 'a' through 'z' incrementing i by 1.

In C++ (Not sure your other language comfort level, you can write

```
for(i='a';i<='z';i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick with the code you show is in poor form. i know this because i do it all 
the time. the code makes an assumtion that the compiler will know the current fixnum 
for each character. #.(char-code #\a) eq [(or maybe eql if you are so inclided) unsigned small integer or unsigned 8 bit character with a return value of a positive fixnum].

The # is a reader macro (I'm fairly sure you know this :). Using two reader macros is
not a great idea but it is fast when the compiler knows the datatype.

I have another example. Need to search for ascii in a binary stream:

```
(defmacro code-char= (byte1 byte2)
  (flet ((maybe-char-code (x) (if characterp x) (char-code x) x)))
       `(the fixnum (= (the fixnum ,(maybe-char-code byte1)
                       (the fixnum ,(maybe-char-code byte2)))))
))
```

Declaring the return type in sbcl will probably insult the complier, but I leave it as a sanity check (4 me not u).

(code-char= #\$ #x36) 
  =>
t

. At least I think so. But somehow I think you might know your way around some macros ... Hmmmm... I should turn on the machine...

If you're seriously interested, there is some assembler for the 286 (8/16 bit dos assembler) that you can use a jump table. It works fast for the PC , I'd have to look it up...